# WiFi with Android Hotspot on Ubuntu 20.04 - internet connection disappears after a while

Tags: networking, 20.04, android

I often connect my laptop (U20.04) via Android  hotspot (Redmi Note 10 5G).

Systematically, after a while, internet connection on my laptop disappears.
In particular, the indicator shows that there is still a wifi connection with my phone, but internet is not available.

If I turn off and turn on wifi on my laptop or turn off and turn on the hotspot on my phone, the internet connection comes back, but in either case after a while the internet connection disappears again.

The settings on the phone are ok (no data limits, no power saving mode).
I'm wondering if the problem is on my laptop and if there are tests I can perform in order to understand what is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you notice this issue with any other device (other than your laptop) connected to the hotspot?

Comment: Yes, also on the laptop of my girlfriend (U20.04 too)

Comment: To be more precise, this happens also sometimes at work when my laptop is connected to the enterprise wifi

Comment: Can you give more details about your laptop? Brand, model number, wifi chipset name, etc.?

Comment: @RandomPerson Laptop: ASUS N56VM, Wifi chipset: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter

Answer (score 0):

#### BE CAREFUL WITH THE FIREWALL

First try:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

If that solves the problem, you can do:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw       allow in  on wlo1
sudo ufw route allow out on enp41s0
```

My system works with:

```
$ sudo ufw status numbered
[ 1] Anywhere on wlo1           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] Anywhere on enp41s0        ALLOW FWD   Anywhere       (out)
[ 3] Anywhere (v6) on wlo1      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 4] Anywhere (v6) on enp41s0   ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)  (out)
```

Only `[ 1]` and `[ 2]` are strictly necessary.